# String Interner giving &str

Tags: rust

The goal of this is to provide a string deduplication pool that can be used as a step between storing `String` everywhere and storing a `usize` and requiring all of the users to know about the interner if they want to figure out what string we're talking about.

The comments in the code should explain what's going on (as `unsafe` should take a proof of correctness), but the basic idea is that the interner loans out `&'a str` where `'a` guarantees that the loan dies with the interner. So long as the interner is alive, the backing `String` is immutable, so the heap-allocated string slice will never move, and the reference is sound.

This is fully documented code, so there's not much more I can say that's not repeating myself.

```
//! A very simplistic string interning interface based around giving out `&str` references
//! rather than some placeholder symbol. This means that strings can be interned in systems
//! based around `&str` without rewriting to support a new `Symbol` type.
//!
//! The typical use case for something like this is text processing chunks, where chunks are very
//! likely to be repeated. For example, when parsing source code, identifiers are likely to come up
//! multiple times. Rather than have a `Token::Identifier(String)` and allocate every occurrence of
//! those identifiers separately, interners allow you to store `Token::Identifier(Symbol)`, and
//! compare identifier equality by the interned symbol.
//!
//! This crate provides the option of using the `&str` directly as the `Symbol` type rather than
//! have another layer of indirection to getting the backing slice. This is good for overlaying
//! on top of an existing system that doesn't need to know about the interning going on behind the
//! scenes. However, this means that comparison of interned strings is still `O(len)` when it could
//! be a simple pointer compare, and interned symbols cannot be persisted across serialization.
//!
//! If it doesn't make sense for you to give up the benefits of using dedicated symbols in order to
//! get the niche benefit of just using `&str`, you should not use this crate. Consider instead
//! [string-interner](https://crates.io/crates/string-interner), which is based off of the Rust
//! compiler's string interner.

#![forbid(missing_debug_implementations, unconditional_recursion, future_incompatible)]
#![deny(bad_style, missing_docs, unsafe_code, unused)]
#![warn(unreachable_pub)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::collections::hash_map::RandomState;
use std::hash::BuildHasher;
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::mem;

// The `StringInterner` contains a lifetime `'a` and loans out string references with that lifetime.
// This guarantees that for as long as the interner is alive, so will the loan.
// Because a `String`'s data lives on the heap and we don't mutate them,
// their data will live until they are freed, and will not move, even as our set grows.
// They will not be freed until we are, as we are an append-only collection of `String`s.

/// A string interner based on a `HashSet`. See the crate-level docs for more.
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct StringInterner<'a, H: BuildHasher = RandomState> {
    #[serde(bound(deserialize = "H: Default"))] // HashSet: Serialize
    arena: HashSet<Box<str>, H>,
    marker: PhantomData<&'a str>,
}

// Cannot be derived with the BuildHasher generic
impl<'a> Default for StringInterner<'a> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        StringInterner {
            arena: HashSet::default(),
            marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

#[inline(always)]
fn coerce<T>(t: T) -> T { t }

#[allow(unsafe_code)]
/// The string interner interface
impl<'a, H: BuildHasher> StringInterner<'a, H> {
    /// Get an interned string slice out of this interner, or insert if it doesn't exist.
    /// Takes borrowed or owned strings. If given a new borrowed string, it will be boxed
    /// and saved into the interner. If given an owned string, no new allocation will
    /// happen for the string.
    ///
    /// Note that the interner may need to reallocate to make space for the new reference,
    /// just the same as a `Vec<String>` would. This cost is amortized to `O(1)` as it is
    /// in other standard library collections.
    ///
    /// If you have an owned string and no longer need the ownership, pass it in directly.
    /// Otherwise, just pass in a string slice.
    ///
    /// See `get` for more about the interned `&str`.
    #[inline]
    pub fn get_or_insert<S>(&mut self, s: S) -> &'a str
    where
        S: AsRef<str> + Into<Box<str>>,
    {
        if self.arena.contains(s.as_ref()) {
            self.get(s.as_ref()).expect("Just entered")
        } else {
            let s: Box<str> = s.into();
            // Get the reference to loan out _after_ boxing up our data
            let _s: &'a str = unsafe { mem::transmute(coerce::<&str>(&s)) };
            self.arena.insert(s);
            _s
        }
    }

    /// Get an interned string slice out of this interner.
    ///
    /// The returned string slice is `&'a str`. This guarantees that the returned slice
    /// will live at least as long as this interner does. All strings in the interner are
    /// never mutated, so the heap-allocated string slice is never going to move, which
    /// makes loaning these references out sound.
    #[inline]
    pub fn get(&self, s: &str) -> Option<&'a str> {
        self.arena
            .get(s)
            .map(|s| unsafe { mem::transmute(coerce::<&str>(s)) })
    }
}

/// Constructors
impl<'a> StringInterner<'a, RandomState> {
    /// Create an empty string interner.
    ///
    /// The backing set is initially created with a capacity of 0,
    /// so it will not allocate until it is first inserted into.
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        StringInterner {
            arena: HashSet::new(),
            marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    /// Create an empty string interner with the specified capacity.
    ///
    /// The interner will be able to hold at least `capacity` strings without reallocating.
    /// If `capacity` is 0, the interner will not initially allocate.
    pub fn with_capacity(capacity: usize) -> Self {
        StringInterner {
            arena: HashSet::with_capacity(capacity),
            marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

/// Constructors to control the backing `HashSet`'s hash function
impl<'a, H: BuildHasher> StringInterner<'a, H> {
    /// Create an empty string interner which will use the given hasher to hash the strings.
    ///
    /// The string interner is also created with the default capacity.
    pub fn with_hasher(hasher: H) -> Self {
        StringInterner {
            arena: HashSet::with_hasher(hasher),
            marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }

    /// Create an empty interner with the specified capacity, using `hasher` to hash the strings.
    ///
    /// The interner will be able to hold at least `capacity` strings without reallocating.
    /// If `capacity` is 0, the interner will not initially allocate.
    pub fn with_capacity_and_hasher(capacity: usize, hasher: H) -> Self {
        StringInterner {
            arena: HashSet::with_capacity_and_hasher(capacity, hasher),
            marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn basic_usage() {
        // Create the interner
        let mut interner = StringInterner::default();

        // Intern some strings
        let a1 = interner.get_or_insert(Box::<str>::from("a"));
        let b1 = interner.get_or_insert(Box::<str>::from("b"));
        let c1 = interner.get_or_insert("c");

        // Get the interned strings
        let a2 = interner.get_or_insert("a");
        let b2 = interner.get_or_insert("b");
        let c2 = interner.get_or_insert("c");

        // Force the interner to move onto the heap
        let interner = Box::new(interner);

        // Get the interned strings from the new location
        let a3 = interner.get("a").unwrap();
        let b3 = interner.get("b").unwrap();
        let c3 = interner.get("c").unwrap();

        // The same strings better be the same pointers or it's broken
        assert_eq!(a1.as_ptr(), a2.as_ptr());
        assert_eq!(a2.as_ptr(), a3.as_ptr());
        assert_eq!(b1.as_ptr(), b2.as_ptr());
        assert_eq!(b2.as_ptr(), b3.as_ptr());
        assert_eq!(c1.as_ptr(), c2.as_ptr());
        assert_eq!(c2.as_ptr(), c3.as_ptr());
    }
}
```

Oh, and I still agree that everyone should prefer to use [string-interner](https://crates.io/crates/string-interner) when possible, this is just a convenience for the small niche where storing a bunch of `String` is too wasteful and yet we still want easy access to the backing `&str`, such as when dealing with an existing system where revamping to use string-interner would take more work, and this provides a middle ground.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [...] the basic idea is that the interner loans out `&'a str` where `'a` guarantees that the loan dies with the interner.

Unfortunately, the way you've written `StringInterner`, that's not true. The following test compiles fine, but invokes undefined behavior (which happens to manifest as the test passing on the Rust Playground):

```
#[test]
fn bad_usage() {
    let s;

    {
        let mut interner = StringInterner::default();

        s = interner.get_or_insert("s");
    } // oops, interner is dropped but we still have a reference to an interned string!

    assert_eq!(s, "s");
}
```

The problem is that by putting a lifetime on `StringInterner` itself and using that lifetime for the returned references, the user of `StringInterner` is *free to choose whatever lifetime they want* (actually, any lifetime that outlives the `StringInterner`, since you can't pass a lifetime that's shorter than the type's own lifetime). Here, the lifetime that's used for `interner` is the lifetime of `s`.

To fix this, the returned references need to have their lifetime connected to the lifetime in the `&self` or `&mut self` parameters on `StringInterner`'s methods. However, if we connect a return value to the lifetime of `&mut self`, that effectively locks `self` until the returned reference goes out of scope (even if the returned reference is an immutable one, it keeps the mutable borrow active). Naturally, this would defeat the point of the interner, so we'll have to stick to `&self`. That means we'll also have to use a wrapper that provides interior mutability in order to mutate the `HashSet`. I'll be using `RefCell` below, which is fine for single-threaded usage; you'll have to switch to `RwLock` if you're going to use the same `StringInterner` on multiple threads.

Regarding good practices, I've noticed that you used `_s` as an identifier in `get_or_insert`. Normally, identifiers beginning with an underscore are used to suppress warnings about the identifier being unused, but you do use it here, so you should not be naming that identifier that way. I renamed `s` and `_s` below. Otherwise, I don't have anything else to say, this is very clean code!

Here's the fixed code. I've left explicit lifetimes in the code to better highlight the difference between your version and my version, but in reality they could all be elided. Note that it's no longer possible to box a `StringInterner` while maintaining references to string slices, so I've commented out some parts of your test function. Also, my `bad_usage` no longer compiles, which is what we want!

```
//! A very simplistic string interning interface based around giving out `&str` references
//! rather than some placeholder symbol. This means that strings can be interned in systems
//! based around `&str` without rewriting to support a new `Symbol` type.
//!
//! The typical use case for something like this is text processing chunks, where chunks are very
//! likely to be repeated. For example, when parsing source code, identifiers are likely to come up
//! multiple times. Rather than have a `Token::Identifier(String)` and allocate every occurrence of
//! those identifiers separately, interners allow you to store `Token::Identifier(Symbol)`, and
//! compare identifier equality by the interned symbol.
//!
//! This crate provides the option of using the `&str` directly as the `Symbol` type rather than
//! have another layer of indirection to getting the backing slice. This is good for overlaying
//! on top of an existing system that doesn't need to know about the interning going on behind the
//! scenes. However, this means that comparison of interned strings is still `O(len)` when it could
//! be a simple pointer compare, and interned symbols cannot be persisted across serialization.
//!
//! If it doesn't make sense for you to give up the benefits of using dedicated symbols in order to
//! get the niche benefit of just using `&str`, you should not use this crate. Consider instead
//! [string-interner](https://crates.io/crates/string-interner), which is based off of the Rust
//! compiler's string interner.

#![forbid(missing_debug_implementations, unconditional_recursion, future_incompatible)]
#![deny(bad_style, missing_docs, unsafe_code, unused)]
#![warn(unreachable_pub)]

#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;

use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::collections::hash_map::RandomState;
use std::hash::BuildHasher;
use std::mem;

// The `StringInterner` loans out string references with the same lifetime as its own.
// This guarantees that for as long as the interner is alive, so will the loan.
// Because a `String`'s data lives on the heap and we don't mutate them,
// their data will live until they are freed, and will not move, even as our set grows.
// They will not be freed until we are, as we are an append-only collection of `String`s.

/// A string interner based on a `HashSet`. See the crate-level docs for more.
#[derive(Clone, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct StringInterner<H: BuildHasher = RandomState> {
    #[serde(bound(deserialize = "H: Default"))] // HashSet: Serialize
    arena: RefCell<HashSet<Box<str>, H>>,
}

// Cannot be derived with the BuildHasher generic
impl Default for StringInterner {
    fn default() -> Self {
        StringInterner {
            arena: RefCell::default(),
        }
    }
}

#[inline(always)]
fn coerce<T>(t: T) -> T { t }

#[allow(unsafe_code)]
/// The string interner interface
impl<H: BuildHasher> StringInterner<H> {
    /// Get an interned string slice out of this interner, or insert if it doesn't exist.
    /// Takes borrowed or owned strings. If given a new borrowed string, it will be boxed
    /// and saved into the interner. If given an owned string, no new allocation will
    /// happen for the string.
    ///
    /// Note that the interner may need to reallocate to make space for the new reference,
    /// just the same as a `Vec<String>` would. This cost is amortized to `O(1)` as it is
    /// in other standard library collections.
    ///
    /// If you have an owned string and no longer need the ownership, pass it in directly.
    /// Otherwise, just pass in a string slice.
    ///
    /// See `get` for more about the interned `&str`.
    #[inline]
    pub fn get_or_insert<'a, S>(&'a self, s: S) -> &'a str
    where
        S: AsRef<str> + Into<Box<str>>,
    {
        let mut arena = self.arena.borrow_mut();
        if arena.contains(s.as_ref()) {
            unsafe {
                mem::transmute(coerce::<&str>(arena.get(s.as_ref()).expect("Just entered")))
            }
        } else {
            let boxed_s: Box<str> = s.into();
            // Get the reference to loan out _after_ boxing up our data
            let s_ref: &'a str = unsafe { mem::transmute(coerce::<&str>(&boxed_s)) };
            arena.insert(boxed_s);
            s_ref
        }
    }

    /// Get an interned string slice out of this interner.
    ///
    /// The returned string slice is `&'a str`. This guarantees that the returned slice
    /// will live at least as long as this interner does. All strings in the interner are
    /// never mutated, so the heap-allocated string slice is never going to move, which
    /// makes loaning these references out sound.
    #[inline]
    pub fn get<'a>(&'a self, s: &str) -> Option<&'a str> {
        self.arena
            .borrow()
            .get(s)
            .map(|s| unsafe { mem::transmute(coerce::<&str>(s)) })
    }
}

/// Constructors
impl StringInterner<RandomState> {
    /// Create an empty string interner.
    ///
    /// The backing set is initially created with a capacity of 0,
    /// so it will not allocate until it is first inserted into.
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        StringInterner {
            arena: RefCell::new(HashSet::new()),
        }
    }

    /// Create an empty string interner with the specified capacity.
    ///
    /// The interner will be able to hold at least `capacity` strings without reallocating.
    /// If `capacity` is 0, the interner will not initially allocate.
    pub fn with_capacity(capacity: usize) -> Self {
        StringInterner {
            arena: RefCell::new(HashSet::with_capacity(capacity)),
        }
    }
}

/// Constructors to control the backing `HashSet`'s hash function
impl<H: BuildHasher> StringInterner<H> {
    /// Create an empty string interner which will use the given hasher to hash the strings.
    ///
    /// The string interner is also created with the default capacity.
    pub fn with_hasher(hasher: H) -> Self {
        StringInterner {
            arena: RefCell::new(HashSet::with_hasher(hasher)),
        }
    }

    /// Create an empty interner with the specified capacity, using `hasher` to hash the strings.
    ///
    /// The interner will be able to hold at least `capacity` strings without reallocating.
    /// If `capacity` is 0, the interner will not initially allocate.
    pub fn with_capacity_and_hasher(capacity: usize, hasher: H) -> Self {
        StringInterner {
            arena: RefCell::new(HashSet::with_capacity_and_hasher(capacity, hasher)),
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn basic_usage() {
        // Create the interner
        let interner = StringInterner::default();

        // Intern some strings
        let a1 = interner.get_or_insert(Box::<str>::from("a"));
        let b1 = interner.get_or_insert(Box::<str>::from("b"));
        let c1 = interner.get_or_insert("c");

        // Get the interned strings
        let a2 = interner.get_or_insert("a");
        let b2 = interner.get_or_insert("b");
        let c2 = interner.get_or_insert("c");

        //// Force the interner to move onto the heap
        //let interner = Box::new(interner); // error[E0505]: cannot move out of `interner` because it is borrowed

        //// Get the interned strings from the new location
        //let a3 = interner.get("a").unwrap();
        //let b3 = interner.get("b").unwrap();
        //let c3 = interner.get("c").unwrap();

        // The same strings better be the same pointers or it's broken
        assert_eq!(a1.as_ptr(), a2.as_ptr());
        //assert_eq!(a2.as_ptr(), a3.as_ptr());
        assert_eq!(b1.as_ptr(), b2.as_ptr());
        //assert_eq!(b2.as_ptr(), b3.as_ptr());
        assert_eq!(c1.as_ptr(), c2.as_ptr());
        //assert_eq!(c2.as_ptr(), c3.as_ptr());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer! And I agree that in this case, making the lifetimes explicit is better for comprehensibility. I've got [an open PR to string-interner](https://github.com/Robbepop/string-interner/pull/5) to enable behavior similar to this on top of the more robust system, if you'd be interested at looking at it and poking open some soundness holes :)